# Phoenix pattern match in controller

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to have 2 index functions in my controller, one if there is call with an id and one if there is an id with a search query string. For some reason the 2nd function is never called.

```
curl localhost:4000/something/15
curl localhost:4000/something/15?search=bob

def index(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
end

def index(conn, %{"id" => id}, "search" => search }) do
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because matching works from the top. If id matches, search is never checked.
You should put more common cases to the bottom, and more particular to the top.

```
def index(conn, %{"id" => id}, "search" => search }) do
end

def index(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
end
```

Maybe you should wrap GET parameters into a map as well, I am not sure. I suppose it is a syntax error here:

```
search }) do
```

Comment: "You should put more common cases to the bottom, and more particular to the top" are words to live by when it comes to pattern matching.